# Jquery - Detect if browser is performing a redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have this code:

```
<span class="d-inline-block social-btn">
  <iframe src="external_url"></iframe>
  <div id="overlap"></div>
</span>
```

There is a button inside iframe.

when an user click on the button, the page redirect to new page in a few seconds.

I want display a "please wait..." message in that time.

```
$(document).on('click', '.social-btn', function(){
    alert("please wait...");
});
```

It dose not work.

also I try this css code to wrapping iframe:

```
.loginWith #overlap{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  top: 0px;
  right: -8px;
  width: 154px;
  height: 34px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

with this, Jquery works but I couldn't click on the button.

if with click event is impossible, Is there a way to detect if browser is performing a redirect?

Comment: you mean the page loaded inside iframe is redirected?

Comment: is the javascript in the iframe or the top level page?

Comment: @john Smith with click on the button inside iframe, it redirect top level page (telegram login)

Comment: @Get Off My Lawn the top level page